# Fragen nach Liste: on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Sind Fragen *on-topic*, deren Antworten Listenform haben?

Damit meine ich nicht etwa Fragen nach Buchempfehlungen, die oft als *opinion-based* geschlossen werden, sondern Fragen nach (möglichst allen) Wörtern, die bestimmten Kriterien entsprechen:
Die sind dann nicht *opinion-based*, aber das Ergebnis ist immer eine Liste, und häufig ist die Frage nicht abschließend zu beantworten.

Wie man mit »Big List™«-Fragen umgehen sollte, wurde im *Meta Stack Exchange* (und sicher auch in den meisten einzelnen *meta*-Bereichen) schon häufiger diskutiert.
[Hier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki) gibt es etwa eine Stellungnahme, in der sich Robert Cartaino (Director of Community Development) gegen solche Fragen ausspricht, *nicht, weil es schlechte Fragen sind, sondern weil sie nicht zum Format von Stack Exchange passen*, nicht einmal als *Community Wiki* (s. Link).

Bilden wir in diesem Stack eine Ausnahme davon, weil wir eine Sprache behandeln? Gibt es gute Gründe, Fragen, die nur in Form einer Liste beantwortet werden können, bei uns zuzulassen, obwohl andere Stacks das anders handhaben?

Answer (score 2):

#### Vorschlag einer Regel

Solche Fragen sind akzeptabel, mit folgenden Einschränkungen bzw. Freiheiten:

- Es ist zu erwarten, dass die vollständige Liste **überschaubar und insbesondere endlich** ist.
  Es kommt dabei weniger auf die Menge der Listeneinträge an als auf den Umfang der gesamten Liste.
  Eine Liste mit zehn Einträgen, die ausführlicher Erklärung bedürfen, kann zu lang sein, während eine Liste mit hundert Einträgen, die für sich stehen, kurz genug sein kann.
  Der Grund hierfür ist, dass wir keine Datenbank ersetzen wollen, da unser Format nicht für deren Pflege ausgelegt ist.
  Bei langen Listen werden zwangsläufig immer Einträge fehlen und ähnliche Probleme auftreten.
  Außerdem muss irgendjemand die Liste lesen wollen.
- Was ein zulässiger Eintrag der Liste ist, ist **keine reine Meinungssache**.
  Es kann aber durchaus sein, dass einige Listeneinträge streitbar sind, weil z. B. die sprachliche Klassifizierung strittig ist.
- **Jede Antwort** auf die Frage strebt an, die **vollständige Liste** zu sein.
  Einzelne Einträge sind keine zulässige Antwort.
  Der Grund hierfür ist, dass es um die Liste geht und es keinen besten Listeneintrag geben kann, der durch Abstimmung ermittelt wird.
  Dies sollte in der Fragestellung klargemacht werden, und falls nicht, von (Community)moderatoren ergänzt werden, um eine Vielzahl von Antworten (die nur einen Eintrag enthalten) zu vermeiden.
  Dieses Kriterium ist ein wesentlicher Unterschied zu den Fragen, um die sich der [zitierter Meta-Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki) dreht, und behebt die meisten angesprochenen Probleme.
- **Mehrere Antworten *können* sinnvoll sein**, wenn sie sich wesentlich in der Darstellung oder Erläuterung der Liste unterscheiden.
  In so einem Fall gibt es eine beste Antwort, nämlich diejenige die am nützlichsten für den Fragesteller (bzw. andere mit derselben Frage) ist.
- Wenn es wahrscheinlich ist, dass Antworten korrigiert werden müssen, z. B. weil sie unvollständig ist, sollten sie **Community-Wikis** sein, um die Pflege der Antworten zu erleichtern und es jedem Nutzer zu erlauben, kleine Korrekturen durchzuführen.
  Dies dürfte in der Mehrzahl der Fälle zutreffen.

#### Beispiele

- [Welche defektiven Verben gibt es in der deutschen Sprache?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/35085/2594)
  – Diese Frage mit Selbstantwort stammt von mir.
  Als ich sie gestellt habe, kannte ich drei Einträge für die Liste, und bis jetzt ist kein neuer aufgetaucht.
  Meine Antwort ist ein Community-Wiki, um es jedem zu ermöglichen, einen weiteren Fund anzufügen, ohne die anderen zu wiederholen.
- [Gibt es eine vollständige Liste von Adjektiven, die einen Umlaut im Komparativ und Superlativ haben?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/20762/2594)
  – Der Kniff der Antwort ist, *wie* man die Liste erlangt und *wieso* sie kurz ist, nicht die Liste selbst.
  Welche Adjektive in der Liste sind, hat sich seit Posten der Antwort nicht geändert, jedoch gab es einige Korrekturen der Zusatzinformation, welche Adjektive sowohl mit als auch ohne Umlaut gesteigert werden können.
  Deswegen ist die Antwort ein Community-Wiki.
  Es ist denkbar, das jemand eine bessere Erklärung oder Systematik für die Liste findet und eine weitere Antwort schreibt.

Answer (score 2):

"List Questions" sind grundsätzlich keine guten Fragen für das Stack Exchange Format. Die Gründe dafür sollten hinreichend bekannt sein, wenn nicht, dann sind sie recht gut in der bereits genannten [Antwort von Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki) zusammengefasst.

Es ist dabei außer Zweifel, dass solche Fragen gut und interessant sein können, aber sie entsprechen eben nicht dem Format von Stack Exchange, bei der es nicht um eine Sammlung von interessanten Fakten geht, sondern um eine Auswahl einer nützlichen Antwort zu einer möglichst spezifischen Frage. Genau das nämlich ist die Stärke unserer Seiten und genau damit unterscheiden wir uns von Foren und Wörterbüchern.

Nur in seltenen Ausnahmefällen kann man auch einmal  nach einer kurzen und endlichen Liste fragen, wie in der [Antwort von Wrzlprmpft hier](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1424/23) ausführlich dargestellt.

In jedem Fall wäre eine Frage viel eindeutiger *on topic*, die sich damit beschäftigt, wie man zu einer solchen Liste gelangt, als eine bloße Frage nach einer solchen Liste.